# For every symmetric matrix A there exists B not singular matrix s.t. $B^{−1}AB$ is diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Theorem**.

For every $q_f:V\to P$ quadratic form exists orthogonal basis, meaning  basis of $V$ on which quadratic form has canonical form.

And my book then says **corollary from theorem.**

> For every symmetric matrix there exists $B$ not singular matrix s.t. $B^{-1}AB$ is diagonal matrix.

I understood proof of theorem but can't understand how from this follows corollary.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the inner product is real. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix. Then $q:x\mapsto\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is a quadratic form on $\mathbb R^n$. By the stated theorem, there is an orthogonal basis $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to which $q$ has a canonical form, i.e., there exist $n$ real numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ such that $q\left(\sum_ix_iv_i\right)=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2$ for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb R$. In terms of matrices this means $x^TV^TAVx=x^T\Lambda x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$, where $V$ is the augmented matrix $\pmatrix{v_1&\cdots&v_n}$ and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. It follows from the polarisation identity that $V^TAV=\Lambda$.

Since $V$ has mutually orthogonal columns, $V=QD$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and diagonal matrix $D$ (more specifically, the $j$-th column of $Q$ is $v_j/\|v_j\|$ and the $j$-th diagonal entry of $D$ is $\|v_j\|$). Therefore $Q^TAQ=D^{-1}\Lambda D^{-1}$. Note that $D^{-1}\Lambda D^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix and $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. The result now follows.

Comment: Thanks for answer I posted my answer can you please see if it is correct?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more how you got $x^TV^TAVx=x^T\Lambda x$

Comment: And please can you elaborate more what you mean$ \langle Ax,x\rangle$

Comment: It's the dot product between $Ax$ and $x$. That is, $x^TAx$.

Answer (score 0):

$(a_1,a_2,..,a_n)$ be basis for $V$.($e_1,e_2,..,e_n$) different basis for $V$.$(e_1,..,e_n)=(a_1,a_2,..,a_n)\times P$.Then    $[x]_e=P\times[x]_a$.Let $[x]_e=X,[x]_a=Y$.
$X=PY$,$X^T=Y^TP^T$.

$q_f(x)=X^TAX=Y^T(P^TAP)Y$=$Y^TBY$=$\sum_{i,j=1}^nb_{ij}y_iy_j$ and from theorem follows that $P^TAP$ is diagonal.

$A=$$\begin{pmatrix}f(e_1,e_1) & f(e_1,e_2) & .. &f(e_1,e_n\\\ f(e_2,e1) & f(e_2,e_2) & .. &f(e_2,e_n)  \\\ .. &.. &..& ..\\\ f(e_n,e_1) &f(e_n,e_2) & .. & f(e_n,e_n) \end{pmatrix}$ where $f$ is bilinear form.

Comment: There are several issues with your answer. (1) What is the $P$ in your answer? (2) You have stated without proof that $P^TAP$ is a diagonal matrix. (3) Where did you use the given theorem? (4) You seem to want to prove that $P^TAP$ is diagonal, but what the corollary says is that $P^{\color{red}{-1}}AP$ is diagonal for some nonsingular matrix $P$.

Comment: By the way, the corollary statement, although true, is actually a bit weird. The usual corollary one finds in textbooks is that $A$ is *orthogonally* diagonalisable, i.e., $P^TAP$ is diagonal for some **orthogonal** matrix $P$. But here the corollary merely states that $A$ is diagonalisable.